# Which all configuration to check before sql server upgrade?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I intend to measure the performance of sql server 2017 vs 2014. I am sure microsoft must have done a lot of tests before upgradation, so the idea here is to see which configuration settings best suite my application when it starts to point to 2017. I want to take those observations under load.

From my initial assessment, i am thinking on taking observations on both 2012 and 2017 machines for the following

```
select * from sys.configurations
select * from sys.servers
select * from sys.dm_os_sys_memory
select * from tempdb.sys.database_files
select * from AdventureWorksDW2014.sys.database_files
select * from tempdb.sys.data_spaces
select * from AdventureWorksDW2014.sys.data_spaces
```

and compare like to like columns. If they are same or meaningfully similar, I can conduct the load and take observations on how the databases are behaving for my application. I want to start with cold buffer.

Is there anything which is indispensable before starting load ?

For making the db with a coldbuffer, I will

a) freeproccache
b) freesessioncache

Comment: Although I've voted to move this to DBA, this could still be too broad for there. One of the best ways, however, to see how an instance performs differently on different versions is use your Dev environment; it's what it's there for. Test, and test and test, until you're happy with the next version and how (well) it performs.

Comment: For the comparisons to be meaningful you should make the machine configurations as close as possible. Also, if you want to give 2017 the biggest lead be sure to upgrade the `compatability_level` for all involved databases - this can change how the query planner builds and assesses plans before executing its final choice.